# How to retrieve data from many to many relationship tables with Doctrine

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

Let say I have 3 tables: `Book`, `Author` and `BookAuthor`.

> - `Book` has `id`, `name`
> - `Author` has `id`, `name`
> - `BookAuthor` has `id`, `book`_id, `author`_id

I want to find all books of an author, and I know `author_id`.  Can anyone show me how to do this with `Doctrine Query Language`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are few ways:

**1**

In action:

```
 $this->books= Doctrine::getTable('BookAuthor')->getBookAuthor($author_id);
```

In model:

```
  public function getBookAuthor($author_id)
        {
            $q = $this->createQuery('a')
                       ->Where('a.author_id=?',$author_id)
                       ->addORDERBY ('created_at DESC');

        return $q->execute();
        }
```

**2**

Sometime  for example you have some parameter in  book table, for example book can be active or not.

In action:

```
 $this->books= Doctrine::getTable('Book')->getBookAuthor($author_id);
```

In model:

```
 public function getBookAuthor($author_id)
        {
            $q = $this->createQuery('a')
                       ->andWhere('a.active=1')
                       ->leftJoin('a.BookAuthor o')
                       ->andWhere('o.author_id=?',$author_id)
                       ->addORDERBY ('created_at DESC');


    return $q->execute();
    }
```